# SQlite query slow just add a "and" judgment

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT distinct
    *
    FROM

    dictionary d  
    join dictionary_with_word dw on dw.dictionary_id=d.dictionary_id  
    join word w on w.word_id=dw.word_id  
    join word_day wd on  wd.word_id=w.word_id  
    join have_buy_dictionary hbd on hbd.have_buy_dictionary_dictionary=d.dictionary_id

    where wd.user_id=777 and wd.word_day=0
```

I use above sql query was fast.

But when i add sql code "and d.dictionary_id=9" At the end of above sql statement :

```
SELECT distinct
    *
    FROM

    dictionary d  
    join dictionary_with_word dw on dw.dictionary_id=d.dictionary_id  
    join word w on w.word_id=dw.word_id  
    join word_day wd on  wd.word_id=w.word_id  
    join have_buy_dictionary hbd on hbd.have_buy_dictionary_dictionary=d.dictionary_id

    where wd.user_id=777 and wd.word_day=0 
    and d.dictionary_id=9
```

Then will be very slow!

why ?

Comment: It might be issue with indexes in your database but it is very hard to guess.

Comment: Probably have to add an index on `word_day`

Comment: Provide `table structure`, `index creation scripts` and `execution plan` if you can, will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Not related to your question, but selecting every field from every table is wasteful because you get the joining fields twice.  I also makes the keyword distinct a waste of keystrokes.